# Bootstrap width slightly too wide on mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm just starting out with [twitter-bootstrap](/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap) and after setting up a simple page it started to appear a few pixels too wide on mobile.
I've narrowed it down to some very simple code:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div>Some text</div>

            <div class="row">
                <div>
                    More text
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

I do have a header in there too, but that's not the problem.

If I remove the **More text** `div`'s it fills the mobile screen nicely, however with them in I can scroll the screen a couple of pixels either side.

Can someone explain why this is happening?

Comment: Try removing the inner class="row"

Comment: If you're going to use Bootstrap at the very least use the markup/classes they provide in the extensive documentation. `.row` divs aren't mean to be children of other `.row ` divs

Comment: From tutorials I have read, I thought the `row` class gives you 12 columns back for nesting?

Comment: @Darren the row gives you 12 columns, then inside the row you size divs with how many columns you want it to take up: `.col-xs-4` takes up 4 columns. http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Boostrap [Docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid), you can't have `row` as **direct** child of `row`

The only time you can have `row` as child of `row` is when you are nesting columns, in this case `row` would be grand child of `row`

- your example using nested `col`s

```css
.col-xs-12 {
  background: red
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div>Some text</div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          More text
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

- your example with no  `row` child

```css
.col-xs-12 {
  background: red
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div>Some text</div>
      <div>More text</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. My actual site was much bigger than my example in the question, and I did have multiple `div`'s in between the `row`'s, however none of those `div`'s used the column attributes. Adding the `col-xs-12` attribute fixed my problems.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to use a `row` class is that inside it you use column class in bootstrap. Thats why it is builded so if you want your div with the text fill the row you apply this:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div>Some text</div>

            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div>
                    More text
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```